# Outlier as a Measurement of Popularity

Tags: self-study, terminology, outliers

**disclaimer**: I'm not a statistician, analyst, or anything professional in this field and have no formal training. This is just a personal project so apologies if this is a naïve question. Please let me know if it needs clarification.

---

I have a dataset of 5000 melodies, and each melody has a number representing the number of hymnals in which it appears.

| name | num_of_hymals_it_appears_in |
| --- | --- |
| melody-1 | 1078 |
| melody-2 | 820 |
| ... | ... |
| melody-4280 | 7 |

Most melodies occur in very few hymnals, and only a very few occur in many resulting is a right skewed distribution

x = # of hymnals;
y = # of melodies

[image]

Would it be considered statistically valid to call the outliers (melodies that occur in 69+ hymnals) the most popular melodies?

Are there other, more preferable ways, to determine popularity (according to my dataset)?

When researching, most resources discuss determine popularity by finding the most frequent item in a dataset, but it would seem to be the opposite in this case.

Any further resources are appreciated.

Comment: As most songs do not become super-popular, this is a typical outlier:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_song

Comment: Sounds good to me. Love to have a link to the more popular ones!

Comment: Welcome! :) To make sure I understand the graph: the first bar represents that in  ca. 50 hymns, the total number of melodies that are repeated is 4235? i.e. hymns 1-50 all have melodies 1-4235 in common? Is there a reason not to plot the table itself, i.e. x = melody index, y = number of hymnals? That would be a more natural way to me, and would show the actual distribution of the melodies. Regarding popularity, you could simply calculate some percentiles of the occurrence of melodies (5%,10% etc.) and then simply decide subjectively how to define an 'outlier' (e.g. must be in top 5%).

Comment: @PaulG the first bar represents that 4235 melodies only occur in 0-50 hymnals